# Running ArcGIS 10.0 Under Virtualenv

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arctoolbox

I am working on a Python package that has a mixture of command line tools and ArcToolbox tools.  For Python development it is really useful to use VirtualEnv, especially when working with installers.  Is there a way to have either ArcMap or ArcCatalog recognize a current VirtualEnv session in Python, so that when a custom tools is executed it is using the VirtualEnv Python paths and packages instead of the default Python paths and packages at c:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not built into the application, but I assume running the batch file that sets up the virtualenv in a `cmd.exe` session and then running arcmap.exe from the same DOS box should get you your virtualenv. ArcMap and friends *will* modify the path slightly to include the install's `arcgisscripting` and `arcpy`.

Edit: you will need to explicitly call the activate_this script from within the Python window in desktop apps to get this to work. If I have a VirtualEnv in `c:\Users\jason\myenv` I will issue `execfile(r'C:\Users\jason\myenv\Scripts\activate_this.py', {'__file__': r'C:\Users\jason\myenv\Scripts\activate_this.py'})` from the Python window in an ArcGIS desktop app to get it running.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work.  I created a VirtualEnv workspace, activated it, then installed a package that I want to test inside of ArcCatalog.  So far so good.  If I open a Python shell inside this VirtualEnv session and import the newly installed packages - the import works.  If I then launch ArcCatalog and try to call one of these packages from a toolbox script - it does not work.  If I look at sys.path from the Python shell inside of ArcCatalog, it is showing the default Python directory for ArcGIS 10.0 (C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0).

Comment: Look into using the `activate_this.py` script also in the same Scripts directory of your VirtualEnv from the Python window in ArcCatalog and friends. I was able to execute `execfile(r'C:\Users\jason\myenv\Scripts\activate_this.py', {'__file__': r'C:\Users\jason\myenv\Scripts\activate_this.py'})` and get my VirtualEnv bootstrapped from within ArcMap.

Comment: Awesome!  That did the trick.